# Python, память и @classmethod

Tags: python, классы

```py
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    # a class method to create a Person object.
    @classmethod
    def fromBirthYear(cls, name, age):
        return cls(name, age) #это специально так чтобы было видно адрес в памяти

person1 = Person('Ctac', 16)#создаём первую переменную класса
print("person_1= ", person1)#выводим информацию о ней
print("@classmethod(after ini person1)= ", Person.fromBirthYear('Stas', 45))#используем декоратор @classmethod
print("@classmethod(after ini person1)= ", Person.fromBirthYear('Bob', 15))#используем декоратор @classmethod
person2 = Person('Jhon', 45)#создаём вторую переменную класса
print("person_2= ", person2)#выводим информацию о ней
print("@classmethod(after ini person2)= ", Person.fromBirthYear('Serge', 245))
print("@classmethod(after ini person2)= ", Person.fromBirthYear('Bill', 715))
person3 = Person('Vova', 345)#создаём третью переменную класса
print("person_3= ", person3)#выводим информацию о ней
person4 = Person('Alis', 145)#создаём четвёртую переменную класса
print("person_4= ", person4)#выводим информацию о ней
print("@classmethod(after ini person4)= ", Person.fromBirthYear('Alis', 315))
print("@classmethod(after ini person4)= ", Person.fromBirthYear('Albert', 125))
person5 = Person('Max', 445)#создаём четвёртую переменную класса
print("person_5= ", person5)#выводим информацию о ней
```

в консоле получаем такой результат:

---

person_1=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b0739b0>
@classmethod(after ini person1)=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b0739e8>
@classmethod(after ini person1)=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b0739e8>
person_2=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b0739e8>
@classmethod(after ini person2)=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b073ba8>
@classmethod(after ini person2)=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b073ba8>
person_3=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b073ba8>
person_4=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b073be0>
@classmethod(after ini person4)=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b073c18>
@classmethod(after ini person4)=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b073c18>
person_5=  <**main**.Person object at 0x10b073c18>

Process finished with exit code 0

---

Вопрос:
почему при создании первого объекта он в памяти по своему адресу, потом я вызываю **@classmethod** после создаю второй объект класса. Так вот **@classmethod** ссылается на тот же блок в памяти, что и второй объект?

Специально я потом ещё несколько подобных манипуляций сделал - **@classmethod** ссылается на блок в памяти созданный следующим экземпляром класса. А мне думалось, что **@classmethod** всегда будет ссылаться на один и тот же блок памяти.

Спасибо!

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov То есть, сборщик мусора моментально удаляет экземпляры классов, не связанные с переменной?

Comment: @nomnoms12 время уничтожения объектов - это деталь реализации интерпретатора. В CPython механизм отслеживания ссылок достаточно простой: не осталось ссылок - можно сразу уничтожать. А вот, например, в pypy этот механизм реализован уже посложнее.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Если коротко, то в CPython два сборщика мусора. Один занимается подсчетом ссылок. И работает он при **каждом** удалении ссылки, **немедленно**. Второй сборщик: `gc` - вызывается по хитрому алгоритму и занимается **только** удалением циклически связанных объектов.

Answer (score 4):

Дело не в использовании `@classmethod`, а в том, что создавая объект с помощью 
конструктора, вы сохраняете ссылку на него в переменную, что не позволяет этот объект сразу уничтожить.

А результат вызова `fromBirthYear` сразу передается в `print`, после этого становится ненужным и потенциально может быть уничтожен. Его место может занять следующий создаваемый объект, что и происходит.

Если сохранять ссылки на создаваемые объекты, результат будет соответствовать ожиданим.

```py
person1 = Person('Ctac', 16)#создаём первую переменную класса
print("person_1= ", person1)#выводим информацию о ней
person11 = Person.fromBirthYear('Stas', 45) #используем декоратор @classmethod
person12 = Person.fromBirthYear('Bob', 15) #используем декоратор @classmethod
print("@classmethod(after ini person1)= ", person11)
print("@classmethod(after ini person1)= ", person12)
```

```py
person_1=  <__main__.Person object at 0x7f591d888208>
@classmethod(after ini person1)=  <__main__.Person object at 0x7f591d888240>
@classmethod(after ini person1)=  <__main__.Person object at 0x7f591d888278>
```

Comment: У вас тут неточность. Память объекта, на который не осталось ссылок, будет **немедленно** помечена, как свободная и может использоваться для других объектов. Причем память **не** будет передана ОС, в общем случае, а останется зарезервированной интерпретатором для новых объектов. С "отсрочкой" работает только `gc`, но он чистит только объекты с циклическими ссылками.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov ни слова о передаче памяти ОС, равно как и о других манипуляциях с памятью, в моем ответе нет. Намеренно.

Comment: > "после этого становится ненужным и **потенциально может** быть уничтожен. Его место может занять следующий создаваемый объект, что и происходит." Однозначно будет уничтожен.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov Их нет в том числе и в этом предложении, которое, к слову, я переписывал раза 3, чтобы оно выглядело именно так, и никак иначе. Потому, что не однозначно. По многим причинам, которые я не хотел описывать, поэтому тщательно подбирал слова.

Comment: Хоть намекните о парочке причин, почему объект, в данном контексте, "потенциально может **не** быть уничтожен"? Прямо заинтриговали! :)

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov [вместо тысячи слов](https://repl.it/@exrnhe/gc). Из параллельного потока возвращается множество объектов, ссылки на которые были им перехвачены, и следовательно объекты не были удалены сразу. Возможно потребуется запустить несколько раз, Иногда поток не успевает ничего перехватить.

Comment: @extrn а как у вас получается создать два объекта  person11 и person12 чтобы они были за разными адресами памяти?
У меня они создаются в одном и том же

Comment: @extrn В каком месте вы получаете объекты **без ссылок**? Ваш код получает адреса объектов, находящихся в процессе создания и вычисления. Так можно вызвать потоки со `sleep` и сказать, что на них нет ссылок. Счетчик ссылок проверяется при каждом доступе к объекту, если ссылок нет - объект отмечается, как удаленный. Это детерминированное поведение. **Если объект существует, на него есть ссылки.**

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov > `Ваш код получает адреса объектов`. Нет, он получает ссылки на объекты. Те самые ссылки, которые обычно хранятся в переменных или в элементах контейнеров. Параллельный поток получает ссылку на объект, который действительно **на тот момент** может быть в процессе создания (не завершен  `__init__`), К моменту окончания работы скрипта в множестве будут полностью сформированные объекты.

Comment: @SpeedyGonzales почитайте ответ внимательно, запустите мой вариант программы, и у вас тоже будут "за разными адресами"

Comment: @extrn В каком месте вы получаете объекты **без ссылок**? Единственный возможный вариант "объекта без ссылки" - финализация, но и это "притянуто за уши", т.к. интерпретатор будет вынужден восстановить объект, отмеченный как удаленный.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov Да что же вы мне с первого же сообщения приписываете слова, которых я не писал. Разумеется на эти объекты есть ссылки, они хранятся в стеке вызова, и по окончании вызова освобождаются. Вот только параллельный поток успевает создать свою собственную ссылку на объект (в данном случае в момент вызова `print`, когда поток освобождает `GIL`). И теперь после освобождения ссылки из стека вызова уничтожения объекта не происходит.